# Access unnamed first column in a data frame?

Tags: dataframe

For example mtcars

```
                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

The first “Column” isn’t named. I want to access it like:

```
mtcars$hp[mtcars$***carnamecolumn***="Mazda RX4”]
```

to ask “What’s the Horsepower of the Mazda RX4?”

Can I use a $accessor for this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a first column, and not _row names_?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see what the issue is.

 [Let’s see if you see it.](https://imgur.com/BjEgwlA)

Those damn curly quotes got me again. I just Copy/Pasted your code to save time and got foiled by the dastardly curly quote yet again.

And yes, they are row names. I know they’re not actually columns, I just used “first column” for lack of a better word. But “Row Names” is the better word I was trying to think of.

Look at the dataset, the mtcars is included in the base package.

I used that dataset b/c I figured anyone could look.

Anyway, how can I access data

Comment: Boom, got it. Code is simply:

mtcars["Mazda RX4","hp”]

Awesome, you using the word “row names” just triggered what I needed to remember top Google what I needed to Google. Thanks!